# length of each word in array by using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have data like this below. In an array we have different words

```
scala> val x=rdd.flatMap(_.split(" "))
x: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[9] at flatMap at <console>:26

scala> x.collect
res41: Array[String] = Array(Roses, are, red, Violets, are, blue)
```

I want find the length of each word in an array in scala

Answer (score 1):

Spark allows you to chain the functions that are defined on a **RDD[T]**, which is RDD[String] in your case. You can add the **map** function following your **flatMap** function to get the lengths.

```
val sentence: String = "Apache Spark is a cluster compute engine"

val sentenceRDD = sc.makeRDD(List(sentence))

val wordLength = sentenceRDD.flatMap(_.split(" ")).map(_.length)

wordLength.take(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

For instance I'll use your value x to show the demonstration:

we can do something like this to find the length of each word in array in scala

```
>x.map(s => s -> s.length)
```

This will print out the following:

> Array[(String, Int)] = Array((Roses,5), (are,3), (red,3), (Violets,7), (are,3), (blue,4))

In the case, if you are using Spark. Then change as follows:

```
>x.map(s => s -> s.length).collect()
```

This will print out the following:

> Array[(String, Int)] = Array((Roses,5), (are,3), (red,3), (Violets,7), (are,3), (blue,4))

If you want only the length of each word then use this:

```
>x.map(_.length).collect()
```

Output:

> Array(5,3,3,7,3,4)

Answer (score 0):

you can just give ...

val a = Array("Roses", "are", "red", "Violets", "are", "blue")
var b = a.map(x => x.length)

This will give you  Array[Int] = Array(5, 3, 3, 7, 3, 4)